# Use parent constructor in child class without redeclaration

Tags: typescript

```js
class A {
  constructor(name: string) {}
}

class B extends A {
  constructor(name: string) {
    super(name);
  }
}
```

In typescript, is it possible for a child class to use the parent's constructor directly without redeclare the signature in the child ?

For example:

```js
class A {
  constructor(name: string) {}
}

class B extends A {}
```

And then we can only:

```js
new B("name");
```

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: It works exactly like you expect [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=12&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1oDswFsCmAuaEALgE4CWaA5itMAPZpHECuwhtxAFBjvo+RQEpE1VIQAWpCADpu2aAF50WbNQC+SdUlCQYAIWjYAHoWxoAJjHgJNdBoWgAjAHLLeJfgvTYA7tF0cAIlkAgRllJCQgA)

Comment: @AlexWayne yup it works!, turn out it was a problem in exporting the class itself. Thanks!

Comment: @AluanHaddad yes, but the problem was somewhere else, Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work. [Based on ES6 class specification](https://2ality.com/2015/02/es6-classes-final.html#default-constructors-for-classes) if you omit the `constructor` in a sub-class, it will use a default that passes arguments to the parent constructor:

> **Default constructors for classes**
>
> If you don’t specify a constructor for a base class, the following definition is used:
>
> ```
> constructor() {}
> ```
>
> For derived classes, the following default constructor is used:
>
> ```
> constructor(...args) {
>   super(...args);
> }
> ```

(TypeScript is a superset of ES6 and follows this specification.)